# Longest path of 1 in a matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, graph, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D boolean matrix in which we can travel in all 8 directions, how can we find the maximum length 
of a path of 1 in it. It's easy to find the largest region of 1, but i want to find the largest path of 1 in it.
The path once visited should not be visited again.
Moving in any direction is counted as one step taken.
Eg:

```
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
```

Here the largest region is 8 but longest path is 6.
How would we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Build an undirected graph based on your matrix: each '1' cell is a node, and there is an edge between each pair of neighbor '1' cells.

Now find the [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) in the graph.